# If I use a reactive client, should the server be reactive too?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I want to use a reactive client (Reactive WebSocketClient i.e ReactorNettyWebSocketClient) to talk to a server which I don't know if it is reactive or not. Does it make sense to use a reactive client to talk to a server which is not reactive?

I tried to connect to a server probably not reactive, and I got this error:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 999 Unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker13.verify(WebSocketClientHandshaker13.java:264)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker.finishHandshake(WebSocketClientHandshaker.java:303)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.WebsocketClientOperations.onInboundNext(WebsocketClientOperations.java:113)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:91)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
```

But I am not sure if this is because of reactive client trying to talk to a non-reactive or a different problem.

Comment: No, "reactive" or not is just a way to implement things. It does not mean that it works differently on the outside, and your error does not happen because the server happens to be implemented in either a reactive or non-reactive style.

Comment: Thanks. So if I call a remote server in a reactive way, what is the difference in camparison with non-reactive way? If both client and server are reactive, then they have subscriber and publisher relationship. What is it like in reactive-client to non-reactive server case?

Comment: they still communicate via rest-protocol over tcp. The difference is the content-type header this will trigger if the connection between the two should be open and maintained (publisher subscriber), vs closed after data has been sent.